# Reading a CSV in Java / Jython

Tags: java, csv, jython

Here's a simple problem:

```
public static double[] stringsToDoubles(String[] inputArr) {
    double[] nums = new double[inputArr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        nums[i] = Double.parseDouble(inputArr[i]);
    }
    return nums;
}

public static double[][] readPointCloudFile(String filename, int n) {
    double[][] points = new double[n][];
    String delimiter = ",";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(filename);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        points[i] = stringsToDoubles(line.split(delimiter));
    }
    return points;
}
```

from jython I import properly, and then call the function as

```
    readPointCloudFile("points.txt", 3)
```

This gives the error

```
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "points.txt"
```

Comment: You never read from the file. You pass the file name to the Scanner and assume that this string is your csv data, but it is just the filename.

Comment: Yea, I think I need to do something like new File(filename) or somthing

Comment: BTW, the [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library can help with this chore of reading CSV files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never read from the file. You pass the file name to the Scanner and assume that this string is your csv data, but it is just the filename. 
Reading a file can be done as follows when you use Java 8:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
[...]

public static double[][] readPointCloudFile(String filename, int n) {
  double[][] points = new double[n][];
  String delimiter = ",";
  String filecontent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename)));
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(filecontent);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      String line = sc.nextLine();
      points[i] = stringsToDoubles(line.split(delimiter));
  }
  return points;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution in the spirit of solving your own problems, but I'll give someone else credit because the other solutions are probably better.

```
 public static double[] stringsToDoubles(String[] inputArr){
     double[] nums = new double[inputArr.length];
     for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
         nums[i] = Double.parseDouble(inputArr[i]);
     }
     return nums;
 }

 public static double[][] readPointCloudFile(String filename, int n) throws FileNotFoundException{
     double[][] points = new double[n][];
     String delimiter = ",";
     try{
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
         for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
             String line = sc.nextLine();
             points[i] = stringsToDoubles(line.split(delimiter));
         }
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
         System.err.println(e.getMessage());
     } finally {
         return points;
     }
 }
```

Comment: This is even easier than my answer. I never work with ``Scanner`` and didnt know it takes a ``File`` argument. Good luck with the further work :)